# how to perform mongodb alternate grouping

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, group-by, aggregation-framework

I've a dev_events collection that holds events related to devices, an event has a type and timestamp. The same event type can be received multiple times with different timestamps.
I want to show for each device, event_type and event_duration by grouping each batch of event_type and calculating date diff (when event starts and when last received before starting a new event type). So, the same event_type may appear multiple times in result but in alternance with other event types.

Here's a sample code I'm using:

```
db = connect("localhost:27017/dev");                

db.dev_events.insert({"device_id"   : 1, "event_type": 1, "event_timestamp" : new Date(2015,09,17,10,10,10)});
db.dev_events.insert({"device_id"   : 1, "event_type": 1, "event_timestamp" : new Date(2015,09,17,10,10,40)});
db.dev_events.insert({"device_id"   : 1, "event_type": 1, "event_timestamp" : new Date(2015,09,17,10,11,10)});

db.dev_events.insert({"device_id"   : 1, "event_type": 2, "event_timestamp" : new Date(2015,09,17,10,11,40)});
db.dev_events.insert({"device_id"   : 1, "event_type": 2, "event_timestamp" : new Date(2015,09,17,10,12,20)});
db.dev_events.insert({"device_id"   : 1, "event_type": 2, "event_timestamp" : new Date(2015,09,17,10,12,55)});

db.dev_events.insert({"device_id"   : 1, "event_type": 1, "event_timestamp" : new Date(2015,09,17,10,13,10)});
db.dev_events.insert({"device_id"   : 1, "event_type": 1, "event_timestamp" : new Date(2015,09,17,10,13,40)});
db.dev_events.insert({"device_id"   : 1, "event_type": 1, "event_timestamp" : new Date(2015,09,17,10,14,00)});

//map reduce
var map = function(){
  emit(this.event_type, this);
}

var reduce = function(key, values){
    var first_happen = values[0].event_timestamp.getTime();
    var last_happen = values[values.length-1].event_timestamp.getTime();

    var event_duration = last_happen - first_happen;
    return {event_type : key, duration : event_duration};
}

var res = db.dev_events.mapReduce(  
                        map, 
                        reduce, 
                        { 
                            query   : {"device_id" : 1},
                            sort    : {"event_timestamp" : 1},
                            out     : {inline : 1} 
                        }
            );

res.find({}).forEach(function(item){ 
    printjson(item); 
});
```

the output was :

```
{ "_id" : 1, "value" : { "event_type" : 1, "duration" : 230000 } }
{ "_id" : 2, "value" : { "event_type" : 2, "duration" : 75000 } }
```

when I was expecting event_type 1 to appear twice. Because event 1 happens for a duration, then event 2 happens for a second duration, then again event 1 happens.

So the output should be like this:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "value" : { "event_type" : 1, "duration" : xxx} }
{ "_id" : 2, "value" : { "event_type" : 2, "duration" : yyy } }
{ "_id" : 1, "value" : { "event_type" : 1, "duration" : zzz } }
```

where xxx, yyy and zzz are durations of events in alternance.

I'm getting confused, I don't know if it's feasable in mongoDB. I'm used to do it in SQL stored procedure without problems.

Any help will be very appreciated,

Regards,

Comment: You cannot get three outputs from your input when there are only two values to group on, despite the timeframes being different. You need another identifier in there to denote the "event" itself in order for there to be any hope of disquishing each as a separate "event".

Comment: Indeed, you're right. But, I was able to do that in SQL via stored procedure, so I For loop through all events related to a device and output result each time event type changes. Any clue for this valid use case?

Comment: You cannot do those sorts of things here. The equivalent process is running a JavaScript eval on the server, but that is a bad idea and just because you could do it on a SQL server supporting that did not make it good either. The correct thing to do is store an identifier rather than looping data to "guess" that the change in dates or boundary means a new key to emit. Also the aggregation framework will be better suited and more performant. Once you add the identifier.